# Compile error: Reference to non-static member function must be called

Tags: c++, function-pointers

The following piece of code aims to sort a 2D vector on the basis of the first column, but it returns an error :

> Line 8: Char 43: fatal error: reference to non-static member function
>   must be called
>           sort(people.begin(),people.end(), sortfunc);
>                                             ^~~~~~~~ 1 error generated.

```
class Solution {
public:

bool sortfunc(const vector<int>& v1, const vector<int>& v2){
    return v1[0]<v2[0];
  }
vector<vector<int>> reconstructQueue(vector<vector<int>>& people) {
    sort(people.begin(),people.end(), sortfunc);
    return people;
  }
};
```

Comment: `sortfunc` needs to be declared static, otherwise it requires an implicit this pointer in order to be called which `std::sort` can't provide. Better: use lambdas

Comment: Thanks a lot @SebastianHoffmann , lamba function works like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @SevastianHoffmann , lambda function does the job.

```
    class Solution {
    public:
}
    vector<vector<int>> reconstructQueue(vector<vector<int>>& people) {
        sort(people.begin(),people.end(), [](const vector<int>& v1, const vector<int>& v2){
        return v1[0]<v2[0];
      });
    return people;
  }
};
```